# jQuery FadeIn() Method in aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fadein

I have a working login page(login.aspx) and I want to add a jQuery script that will show a div(fade in effect) when the user inputs are incorrect.

What I want to do is for the div to show after an unsuccessful login of the user just above the Login button.

What is happening.. is that after the unsuccessful login of the user, the div shows but it becomes hidden again after few seconds.

Here's my jQuery script:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function error() {
            $('.toggleBtn').click(function(){
                $('.toggler').fadeIn();
            });
        });
</script>
```

my div section:

> ```
> <div class="toggler">
>       <p>
>        Incorrect login credentials.               </p>
> </div>
> ```

my code-behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "errorHandler", "error();", true);
```

Comment: It works fine , what is issue ? http://jsfiddle.net/6cr08hf5/

Comment: in my case it works also but after a second or 2 it hides again.

Comment: Justs a minute some other jScript caused error  , try using `toggler1` 

`<div class="toggler1">
      <p>
       Incorrect login credentials.               </p>
</div>
` 

And 

`<script>
        $(document).ready(function error() {
            $('.toggleBtn').click(function(){
                $('.toggler1').fadeIn();
            });
        });
</script>`

Comment: i tried to inject other jquery scripts on the login page and still the effects disappear after a second